# If I reinstantiate a Scanner, does the old one close?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this code:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(myFile);
// some code
fileReader = new Scanner(myFile);
// some more code
fileReader.close();
```

It does what I want it to (starts the reader again from the top of the file) but have I left a Scanner open by instantiating twice and only closing once? Should I have closed before I reinstantiated? What I have works, but I'd like to know whether it's good practice or not.

Comment: Yes its a good practice to close it. And No is the answer for your title question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I reinstantiate a Scanner, does the old one close?

Nope.

> Should I have closed before I reinstantiated?

Yup.

> What I have works, but I'd like to know whether it's good practice or not.

It is bad practice.  It is a *resource leak*.  If you do that too much, you are likely to find that `new Scanner(myFile)` will throw an exception, complaining that it has run out of file descriptors (or something like that).

The recommended practice is to use the *`try` with resources* syntax to ensure that the scanner gets closed no matter what.  (Or if you are "old school" and / or stuck on Java 6 or earlier ... close the scanner in a `finally` block ... carefully.)

Example:

```
   try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(myFile)) {
      // some code
   }
   try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(anotherFile)) {
      // some more code
   }
```

It is not necessary to explicitly close either `fileReader`.  Each `try` has an implicit `finally` block that calls `close` on all of the `Closeable` resources like the `Scanner` objects we created there.)